# auto indentation of csharp lambda in Vim

Tags: c#, vim, lambda

Let me know auto indentation of csharp lambda.
I use [OrangeT/vim-csharp](https://github.com/OrangeT/vim-csharp). But this plug-in doesn't support indentation of lambda.

Example

```
AttackButton.OnClickObservable().Subscribe(_ =>
        { 
            Player.DoSomething();
            //blabla
        });
```

Ideal

```
AttackButton.OnClickObservable().Subscribe(_ =>
{
    Player.DoSomething();
    //blabla
});
```

Plz teach me What it would be changed in the indent/cs.vim.

Comment: Did you tried `:set autoindent` or `:set smartindent` ?

Comment: i already tried `:set smarrtindent`, `:set cindent` and `:set autoindent`. but indentation won't change.

Comment: Keep the cursor on `{` and then press `<<`. After that press, `=i{`. Did you saw the expected alignment?